# Oozie XML schema error E0701

Tags: xml, oozie

Below is a simple Oozie script that I tried to run

```
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.2" name="simple-Workflow">
   <start to="Create_Table"/>
   <!—Step 1 -->
   <action name="Create_Table">
      <hive xmlns="uri:oozie:hive-action:0.2">
          <job-tracker>${resourceManager}</job-tracker>
          <name-node>${namenode}</name-node>
  <script>${create}</script>
      </hive>
      <ok to="drop_Table"/>
      <error to="kill_job"/>
   </action>
   <!—Step 2 -->
   <action name="drop_Table">
      <hive xmlns="uri:oozie:hive-action:0.2">
         <job-tracker>${resourceManager}</job-tracker>
         <name-node>${namenode}</name-node>

     <script>${drop}</script>
          </hive>
      <ok to="end"/>
      <error to="kill_job"/>
   </action>
   <kill name="kill_job">
      <message>Job failed</message>
   </kill>
   <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

Then I tried running Oozie and got the following errors - E0701: XML schema error, The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.

I then ran Oozie validate and got another error - org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; Premature end of file.

I tried looking it up and could not find a solution to solve the problem. I did not use the property file. All the variables in the XML are supposed to be there, but I put them as variables in here.

Comment: It may be some kind of copy/paste or autocorrect problem, but the comments in your XML are not well formed. `<!—Step 1 -->` should be `<!--Step 1 -->`

Comment: @MichaelKay Thank you so much. That's the issue. I was so dumb :(

Comment: FYI, I found this simply by copying/pasting the XML into the oXygen XML editor and looking for the error highlighting. Not difficult.

Answer (score 2):

The comments in your XML are not well formed. `<!—Step 1 -->` should be `<!--Step 1 -->`.

Comment: Sometimes using a validator also helps...
http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/#.XRzpCflKi-s